# How can I make this IF block shorter?

Tags: java

How can I make this code shorter and simpler?

```
if ((fBody.equals("block") && sBody.equals("ball")) || (fBody.equals("ball") && sBody.equals("block"))) // CODE
if ((fBody.equals("wall") && sBody.equals("bonus")) || (fBody.equals("bonus") && sBody.equals("wall"))) // CODE
```

And so on.

Comment: this is short and simple enough

Comment: Why would you like to do that? IMHO, conditionals should be self explanatory than short

Comment: `a + b == c + d && a * b = c * d`

Comment: This is more shorter: `(a==c&&b==d)||(a==d&&b==c)`. Seriously, you can use basic logical facts to attempt to simplify. For example, `X && (Y || Z)` can be written `(X && Y) || (X && Z)` and `X || (Y && Z)` can be written `(X || Y) && (X || Z)`. Play with that in your case and see what you come up with. It may or may not lead you to something simpler.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog that's not really shorter but it is less self-explanatory

Comment: @meowgoesthedog ahh yes, very good then

Comment: Because the full code looks like that:

Comment: if ((a.equals("block") && b.equals("ball")) || (a.equals("ball") && b.equals("block"))) // CODE
if ((a.equals("wall") && b.equals("bonus")) || (a.equals("bonus") && b.equals("wall"))) // CODE
And so on.

Comment: I would rather make it longer and use more meaningful names than a, b, c, d ... single character names are devil's spawn.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you "want"? Shorter and simpler are not defined, and many cases you can't make a single improvement that gets you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a list containing all the possible 'correct' pairs and then looping on it:

```
class Pair {
    String sBody;
    String fBody;

    public String getsBody()
    {
        return sBody;
    }

    public String getfBody()
    {
        return fBody;
    }
}

boolean check(List<Pair> list, String sBody, String fBody) {
    for (Pair pair : list) {
        if (pair.getsBody().equals(sBody) && pair.getfBody().equals(fBody)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

you will still have to populate this list somehow beforehand of course

Answer (score 2):

I would put the literals "ball", "wall", etc. into an `Enum`.

```
public enum ObjectType {

    BLOCK("block"),
    BALL("ball"),
    BONUS("bonus"),
    WALL("wall");

    private String objectType;

    ObjectType(String objectType) {
        this.objectType = objectType;
    }

    public String getObjectType() {
        return objectType;
    }

    public boolean equals(String body) {
        return objectType.equalsIgnoreCase(body);
    }
}
```

Then I would keep `sBody` and `fBody` in a pair.

```
public class Pair {

    private final String fBody;
    private final String sBody;

    public Pair(String fBody, String sBody) {
        this.fBody = fBody;
        this.sBody = sBody;
    }

    public String getfBody() {
        return fBody;
    }

    public String getsBody() {
        return sBody;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pair{" +
                "fBody='" + fBody + '\'' +
                ", sBody='" + sBody + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Then I would leverage Java 8's `Predicate` and create a list of predicates as such:

```
public final class Predicates {

    public static final List<Predicate<Pair>> PREDICATES =
            Arrays.asList(
                    isBlockBall(),
                    isBlockBall()
                    // add rest of your predicates
            );

    private Predicates() {
        // we do not need to instantiate this
    }

    public static Predicate<Pair> isWallBlock() {
        return p -> ObjectType.WALL.equals(p.getfBody())
                && ObjectType.BLOCK.equals(p.getsBody());
    }

    public static Predicate<Pair> isBlockBall() {
        return p -> ObjectType.BLOCK.equals(p.getfBody())
                && ObjectType.BALL.equals(p.getsBody());
    }
}
```

You can then test your condition as follows:

```
public class TestingPairs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String fBody = "block";
        final String sBody = "ball";
        Pair pair = new Pair(fBody, sBody);
        final Optional<Predicate<Pair>> conditionMet = PREDICATES.stream().filter(pairPredicate -> pairPredicate.test(pair))
                .findFirst();

        if (conditionMet.isPresent()) {
            // do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```